# ¿Cómo puedo poner un gif animado?

Tags: python, pygame

Quisiera poder introducir un gif animado en mi proyecto PyGame.

http://gifmaniacos.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/space-gif-espacio-gif-movimiento-gifmaniacos.es-57.gif

Quiero poner este gif de fondo de mi juego pero no se como.
Ya he buscado en muchos sitios web y vídeos pero no consigo mostrar la animación.

---

**Edición:**

He intentado lo que me dijo FJSevilla pero me sale este error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python33\arri\main.py", line 56, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "C:\Python33\arri\main.py", line 37, in main
>     images = load_images(path='background_frames')
>   File "C:\Python33\arri\main.py", line 26, in load_images
>     images =  [pygame.image.load(path + os.sep + file_name).convert() for file_name in sorted(os.listdir(path))]
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: 'background_frames\\*.*'
> ```

[image: y ya tengo la carpeta con los frames]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como comenta Galante64 en su respuesta SDL2 y PyGame no soportan GIF animados, aunque el formato es soportado solo se carga el primer frame.

Una forma de simular un gif animado es conseguir todos los frames del GIF como comenta Galante64 y usando un **sprite** ir iterando sobre ellos de forma cíclica, con un delay de acuerdo al gif (en tu caso todos los frames tienen un delay de 30 ms).

Este es un ejemplo simple usando tu gif:

```
import itertools
import os
import sys
import pygame


class AnimatedBackground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position, images, delay):
        super(AnimatedBackground, self).__init__()

        self.images = itertools.cycle(images)
        self.image = next(self.images)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(position,  self.image.get_rect().size)

        self.animation_time = delay
        self.current_time = 0

    def update(self, dt):
        self.current_time += dt
        if self.current_time >= self.animation_time:
            self.current_time = 0
            self.image = next(self.images)


def load_images(path):
    images =  [pygame.image.load(path + os.sep + file_name).convert() for file_name in sorted(os.listdir(path))]
    return images

def main():
    pygame.init()
    SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 440
    BACKGROUND_COLOR = pygame.Color('black')
    FPS = 60
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    images = load_images(path='background_frames') 
    background = AnimatedBackground(position=(0, 0), images=images, delay = 0.03)
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(background)

    while True:
        dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        all_sprites.update(dt)

        screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Los frames del gif los puedes obtener con múltiples programas de tratamiento de imágenes, con Pillow/PIL y Python o incluso con servicios disponibles en la web. Estos frames están contenidos en la carpeta `backgrown_frames` en el ejemplo, y son 181 frames para tu gif. Es importante que los frames estén nombrados de forma que puedan ser ordenados de forma adecuada quedando en orden de aparición correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado obtenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso el gif tiene el mismo delay entre frames, no obstante, no es complicado adaptar la clase para que acepte un delay diferente por cada frame. Lo podemos hacer aceptando una listas de tuplas `(Surface, delay)` para el argumento `images` del inicializador y actualizando en el método `update` el atributo `animation_time` junto al frame correspondiente.

> **Nota:** El código está probado en Python 3.6  con PyGame 1.9.3. En principio ha de funcionar como tal en Python 2.7 sin problemas.

Comment: ¿tengo python 3.3 con pygame 1.9.2, con esa versión funciona?

Comment: @AndresGomez si debe funcionar sin problemas, no hay nada que no estuviera ya implementado en la 3.3 (a no ser que algo se me pase). Si no tienes inconvenientes muy grandes si que te aconsejaría actualizar a Python 3.6 o al menos a alguna versión con soporte actual, pero debe funcionar sin problemas con py 3.3. Si tienes algún problema no dudes en comentar. Saludos.

Comment: he actualizado mi pregunta

Comment: @AndresGomez cuando actualizes no borres lo anterior porque la pregunta y sus respuestas pierden el sentido y la idea del sitio es que ambas sirvan de ayuda a otros usuarios. La he editado por ti. El problema está en que tu carpeta se llama "backgroun_frames" y debe ser "background_frames", te falta la "d"  de "backgroun**d**". Puedes llamar como quieras la carpeta y tenerla en la ruta que quieras, solo debes pasar la ruta correcta en `images = load_images(path='/ruta/a/la/carpeta')`

Comment: no, sigue saliendo el mismo error ¿sera por el numero de frames que hay?

Comment: @AndresGomez no me habia dado cuenta pero también tienes una "w" en vez de una "u". tu carpeta se llama "backgrown_frames" y debe ser "background_frames". Casi mejor que copies y pegues el nombre a ver si terminamos :). El número de frames no importa, de eso se encarga la función. Si hay dos toma dos y si hay 200 toma 200, solo debes preocuparte  de que la carpeta solo contiene imágenes...

Comment: !!!oh!!!gracias amigo ya me a funcionado solo una ultima pregunta ¿puedo poner ese gif de fondo de un jugo que he echo?

Comment: @AndresGomez la idea general es añadir este sprite el primero a tu display en el main loop. Es decir hacer `screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)`  antes de agregar cualquier imagen, sprite, etc en tu ciclo `while`. Esto hará que el resto de imágenes se superpongan al fondo cuando sean dibujadas en cada iteración del mainloop.

Comment: pongo todo el codigo dentro de un while y solo me aparece la animación no el resto ¿como hago que se superpongan ?

Comment: @AndresGomez no se trata de copiar todo el código, la función main en mi código solo se encarga de crear una aplicación simple donde probar el sprite y no debe estar en tu código como tal. Debes adaptar lo que se hace en ella a tu juego, añadir el sprite en tu propio mainloop que tienes seguro en tu código (ciclo while infinito donde se comprueban los eventos y se actualiza la ventana).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67702/discussion-between-andres-gomez-and-fjsevilla).

Answer (score 1):

Pygame no soporta gifs animados de forma nativa (como puedes ver en su [documentación](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html)), por lo que tienes dos opciones:

- Utilizar la librería [GIFImage](http://www.pygame.org/project-GIFImage-1039-.html).
- Separar el gif en todos sus frames (lo cual puedes hacer incluso [desde Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904940/python-converting-gif-frames-to-png) o utilizando herramientas como GIMP) y cargar las imágenes de frame en frame, lo cual puede dar una sensación de animación muy similar a la de un gif.